# SQL: In case not use LIKE when variable is NULL

Tags: sql

I need the next: When variable `@SCOPE` is not null then use "`like`" else ignore this filter.

first sql:

```
DECLARE @SCOPE varchar = '%test%'
select id, scope from delivery 
where scope like @SCOPE
```

and second when scope is null

```
DECLARE @SCOPE varchar = NULL
select id, scope from deliver
```

something like this:

```
DECLARE @SCOPE varchar = null
select id, scope from delivery 
where
scope like
(CASE 
    WHEN @SCOPE IS NULL THEN scope ELSE @SCOPE
END)
```

But this is NOT CORRECT SQL query. I'm not need to use "`like`" when scope is null.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `or`:

```
where @scope is null or scope like @scope
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing the same thing.

```
  select * from delivery where ISNULL(scope,'') like ISNULL(@scope, ISNULL(scope,''))
```

Comment: When scope='test' - it's not work on MS SQL. Show 'test' and null values in column scope. But I need to show only 'test' when scope='test'

Comment: This work: DECLARE @SCOPE varchar(80) = '%test%'
select id,scope from delivery where ISNULL(scope,'') like ISNULL(@scope, ISNULL(scope,'')) . The problem was in varchar(80). By default lengths is 1 and as result it not work.